# Prevent unwanted parameter values for my GET API calls for improved security

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest, security, owasp

I run a website using ASP.NET. My API (GET request) URI is formatted like so:
https://www.example.com/api/results/?country=&city=&value=

However, when runing a vulnerability test on my site it came up with errors around this, basically adding parameter values:

- Possible Sensitive Directories/Files Detected, e.g. for URL https://www.example.com/api/results/?country=&city=admin/access_log&value=
- Content Injection
  https://www.example.com/api/results/%20Site%20is%20moved%20to%20wastest.indusface.com%
  20kindly%20visit%20wastest.indusface.com.%20?country=undefined&city=undefined&value=
- Iframe Injection, e.g. for URL
  https://www.example.com/api/results/?country=%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwas.indusfac
  e.com%2F2085%22%20class%3D'haikumsg'%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E&city=&value=

So basically, I think it all boils down to the same issue: an issue with unwanted parameter values for my API, but I'm not sure how to prevent this. I have many parameters and I could check each input value manually but that seems like an uphill battle and would also impact application performance.

What can I do to resolve this "parameter stuffing"?

Here's my API definition:

**Iexample.vb**

```
       <OperationContract()>
        <Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate:="results/?country={country}&province={province}&city={city}&value={value}")>
```

**example.svc.vb**

```
    Public Function results(ByVal country As String, ByVal province As String,
        ByVal city As String, ByVal value As String) As Stream Implements Iexample.results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern you could apply is to implement validation functions, like

```
Protected Function IsValidFoobarParams(ByVal ParamArray args() As String) As Boolean
    For Each param As String In args
        If Not IsValidFoobarParam(param) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

You will need to implement `IsValidFoobarParam` yourself to have a validation for the parameter, returning a boolean.  You can call the function above like

```
    Dim IsValid As Boolean = IsValidFoobarParam(param1, param2, param3)
```

If you need some other validation as well, let's call it `IsValidLoremIpsumParam`, then you can do something like this

```
    Dim IsValid As Boolean = IsValidFoobarParam(param1, param2, param3) AndAlso IsValidLoremIpsum(param1, param3)
```

In the example above I have ommitted `param2` from the second validation on purpose, to illustrate that if you use [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/parameter-arrays), then you can pass as many parameters as you like, 0 or more.

One last issue is remaining. You maybe have multiple types, in which case you may want to have separate validations for separate types, or type conversions. But, the basic pattern is to:

- implement a validation function for each validation type that takes a single value and returns `Boolean`
- implement a validation function for each validation type that takes an array of parameters, loops it, calls the corresponding singular validation function for each of them, `Return False` if any of them fails to be valid and `Return True` at the end of the loop
- call the function that loops a parameter array from where you are to validate, so, you implement your validation types once and reuse them at all your API functions as you please by simply calling the functions

Comment: Thank you! Is checking each parameter really the best practice way of preventing invalid API values? Does it not slow down API requests? Thanks again

Comment: Consider it this way: Your parameters need to be checked somehow. So, you will need something to check all your parameters. Whatever that something and somehow is, either explicitly, or under the hood, it will need to check your URL (regexp, for example) or individual parameters. Since your parameters might be very different from each-other and they may need several validations, having a parameter-by-parameter check allows you to handle the differences of validation if needed. Now, if you are thinking whether the validation would slow down your request handling...

Comment: @Adam consider it this way: you are using a computer, a server, whose job is to compute things. Having 7 or 8 validation for maybe 10 parameters would mean maybe 80 String operations. That shouldn't be a problem or a difficulty. But you could try it yourself by implementing a String operation that you are afraid of in terms of performance and try executing it in a loop while measuring time. You will likely experience it to be much much faster than your human perception would expect. But do try it and let me know about the result.